# Hammer.js Pinch Event in Android

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, pinch, hammer.js

When using Hammer.js with jquery mobile, its "Pinch" event isn't working well in Android, but it's working well in iOS.

I'm developing a mobile mail system like Gmail, so the detail page of an email will be zoomed in/out using both jquery-mobile and hammer.js.

Besides, it will be needed to enable the vertical scrolling actions including the div area that Hammer was applied to.

Below is the sample code for that.

```
// Pinch Event
var ham = $('.mail_body').hammer({
    drag: true,
    drag_block_vertical: false,
    drag_block_horizontal: false,
    drag_lock_to_axis: false, 
    prevent_default: false,
    prevent_mouseevents: true,
    show_touches: false,
    stop_browser_behavior: {},
    swipe: false,
    touch: true
});
```

Can anyone help me?

Thank you in advance for your help.